# Angular2 - Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'enum'

Tags: enums, angular-cli

I have some proble. I want to create a really simple enumeration called `AlertType` to keep my alert types. Here is my code

**AlertType.ts**

```
export enum AlertType {
  WARMING = {icon: "exclamation-triangle", name: "warming"},
  SUCCESS = {icon: "check-circle", name: "success"}
}
```

But if I want to render my application, console returns error

> Type '{ icon: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'AlertType'.

Do you know, why I still have errors? Thanks for all your answers

Comment: An `enum` in TypeScript can only contain numeric types, not objects. You will have to rethink this a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can do to having enums with an object as the value is by using static class properties.

Try the following:

```
export class AlertType {
  static readonly WARNING = { icon: "exclamation-triangle", name: "warning" };
  static readonly SUCCESS = { icon: "check-circle", name: "success" };
}
```